# LinearLayout larger than screen width is not adding items

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-screen

first of all, `App.getInstance().getWidth(`) gives me screen width.

I am creating this LinearLayout:

```
mainContainer = new LinearLayout(context);  
        mainContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

It is horizontal, and it haves two items, this:

```
adContainer = new RelativeLayout(context);
        adContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        adContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(App.getInstance().getWidth(), App.getInstance().getHeight()));
        adContainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
mainContainer.addView(adContainer);
```

and this:

```
tabView = new ImageView(context);
        tabView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100,140));
        tabView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab);
        mainContainer.addView(tabView);
```

I try moving the layout with TranslateAnimation, but i see that it does not show the view `tabView` on the right of adContainer, so i tested putting `mainContainer` with a startX position of `-App.getInstance().getWidth()/2` and i can see half of `adContainer` but i still can't see `tabView`

The only way to see tabView is setting adContainer width to less than `App.getInstance().getWidth()`. It is very strange...

Why i can't see any items added into a layout but in a x position larger than screen width?

Thanks

Comment: so... no one can with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have given wrap content in the layout parameters for linear layout, so the linear layout is wrapped around the relative layout and image view. Try using MatchParent.

```
mainContainer = new LinearLayout(context);  
    mainContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: Could you share more code? According to the code provided I can't see you setting orientation of linear layout to horizontal, have you done that in ur code?

Comment: i shared you all the code of the layouts... the other code is logic independent from the layouts

Comment: Also u are setting the RelativeLayout to fill the entire screen

Comment: No, it is App.getInstance().getWidth(), that gives the width of the screen. I am not using match parent

Comment: adContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(App.getInstance().getWidth(), App.getInstance().getHeight()));    This means the layout is going to match the width and height of the screen doesn't it?!

Comment: yes, i want that layout gets 100% of the width of the screen. The tabview must be on the right of that layout

Comment: so, you can't help with this problem?